# Enzyme `.find(selector)` does not seem to find a selector

Tags: javascript, css, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

`element.find('span.active-nav-option')` returns nothing whilst `element.find('.active-nav-option')` returns the span. The point of the test is to find out if a `span` was rendered instead of a `Link`.

Component is as follows:

```
const PageNav = ({
  router,
  slides,
}) => (
  <nav className="PageNav">
    <span className="chevron">
      <MoreVerticalIcon
        strokeWidth="0.5px"
        size="3em"
      />
    </span>
    <ul className="nav-links">
      {mapSlides(slides, router)}
    </ul>
    <style jsx>{styles}</style>
  </nav>
)

function mapSlides(slides, router) {
  return Object.entries(slides)
    .sort((
      [, { order: a }],
      [, { order: b }],
    ) => a - b)
    .map(([slidename, { altText, order }]) => {
      const isActiveLink = router.query.slidename === slidename
      const navItemClassnames = [
        'nav-item',
        isActiveLink && 'active',
      ]
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join(' ')

      const Element = isActiveLink
        ? props => <span {...props} />
        : Link

      const liInternalElementProps = {
        ...(isActiveLink && { className: 'active-nav-option' }),
        ...(!isActiveLink && {
          href: `/CVSlide?slidename=${slidename}`,
          as: `/cv/${slidename}`,
        }),
      }

      return (
        <li
          className={navItemClassnames}
          key={order}
        >
          <Element {...liInternalElementProps}>
            <a title={altText}>
              <img
                src={`/static/img/nav-icons/${slidename}.svg`}
                alt={`An icon for the ${slidename} page, ${altText}`}
              />
            </a>
          </Element>
          <style jsx>{styles}</style>
        </li>
      )
    })
}
```

**To Reproduce**
run this line as a test:

```
const wrapperOne = shallow(
    <PageNav
      slides={mockSlides}
      router={{
        query: {
          slidename: 'hmmm',
        },
      }}
    />
  )

const spanExists = wrapperOne
  .find('.active-nav-option')
  .html() // outputs <span class="active-nav-option">...</span>
// so one would expect span.active-nav-option to work?

const spanDoesNotExist = wrapperOne
  .find('span.active-nav-option')
  .html() // throws an error `Method “html” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.`
// subsequently if I use `.exists()`  to test if the element exists, it returns nothing.
```

**Expected behavior**
`element.find('span.active-nav-option')` should return the `span`. I think? I initially thought this was to do with `shallow` vs `mount` but the same happens with mount. Am I being an idiot here? Is this something to do with the map function in the component?

- OS: OSX
- Jest 23.5
- enzyme 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's because you don't use `<span/>` directly in JSX returned from `render` method but assign it to a variable and then add that variable to JSX.

If you execute `console.log(wrapperOne.debug())` you will see the following result (I've removed styles and components that you didn't provided):

```
<nav className="PageNav">
  <span className="chevron" />
  <ul className="nav-links">
    <li className="nav-item active">
      <Component className="active-nav-option">
        <a title={[undefined]}>
          <img src="/static/img/nav-icons/0.svg" alt="An icon for the 0 page, undefined" />
        </a>
      </Component>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see, you have `<Component className="active-nav-option">` instead of `<span className="active-nav-option">` thus `span.active-nav-option` can't find anything.